# Export CloudWatch Logs to S3 using Lambda Using JAVA as Runtime language

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to export the previous day logs from Cloudwatch to S3 using lambda. I have found few reference code for the same but most of them have used Python as Runtime language.

I want to use JAVA as my runtime language, so how can we access the logs and write the file in s3 using JAVA

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  Using the [AWSLogsClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogsClient.html) you read the log files you want and then, using the [AmazonS3Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html) you create one or more objects.  Forget Lambda at first and get the code running.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example of how you can do this in Java lambda function.

Note: this examples stores everything from CloudWatch logs to S3 between the given timestamp. You can always add logic to filter some lines out, or modify it as you need it.

```
private boolean saveLogsToS3(Context context) {
    final String logGroupName = "log-group-name";

    String awsRegion = System.getenv("AWS_REGION");
    AWSLogs logsClient = AWSLogsClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion(awsRegion)
            .build();

    // START date+time you want to get streams for
    // yesterday BEGINNING of day
    DateTime startTime = new DateTime()
            .minusDays(1)
            .hourOfDay().withMinimumValue()
            .minuteOfHour().withMinimumValue()
            .secondOfMinute().withMinimumValue()
            .millisOfSecond().withMinimumValue();

    // END date+time you want to get streams for
    // yesterday END of day
    DateTime endTime = new DateTime()
            .minusDays(1)
            .hourOfDay().withMaximumValue()
            .minuteOfHour().withMaximumValue()
            .secondOfMinute().withMaximumValue()
            .millisOfSecond().withMaximumValue();


    // first, get ALL streams within the date range
    DescribeLogStreamsRequest describeLogStreamsRequest = new DescribeLogStreamsRequest()
            .withLogGroupName(logGroupName)
            .withDescending(true)
            .withOrderBy(OrderBy.LastEventTime)
            .withLimit(50);;
    DescribeLogStreamsResult describeLogStreamsResult = null;
    ArrayList<LogStream> logStreams = new ArrayList<>();

    do {
        if(describeLogStreamsResult != null) {
            describeLogStreamsRequest.setNextToken(describeLogStreamsResult.getNextToken());
        }

        describeLogStreamsResult = logsClient.describeLogStreams(describeLogStreamsRequest);
        logStreams.addAll(describeLogStreamsResult.getLogStreams());
    } while (describeLogStreamsResult.getNextToken() != null && !describeLogStreamsResult.getNextToken().isEmpty());


    context.getLogger().log("logStreams count: " + logStreams.size());


    // now, get logs from each stream as store each stream as it's own file
    DateTime dateTime;
    String fileName;

    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion(awsRegion)
            .build();

    // s3 client
    if (s3Client == null) {
        context.getLogger().log("s3 client is null?!");
        return false;
    }

    String bucketName = "logs-backup-bucket-name";

    for(LogStream logStream : logStreams) {
        // get all events within a stream
        GetLogEventsRequest getLogEventsRequest = new GetLogEventsRequest()
                .withLimit(1000)
                .withLogGroupName(logGroupName)
                .withStartTime(startTime.getMillis())
                .withEndTime(endTime.getMillis())
                .withLogStreamName(logStream.getLogStreamName());
        GetLogEventsResult getLogEventsResult = null;
        ArrayList<OutputLogEvent> logEventsForStream = new ArrayList<>();

        do {
            if(getLogEventsResult != null) {
                getLogEventsRequest.setNextToken(getLogEventsResult.getNextForwardToken());
            }

            getLogEventsResult = logsClient.getLogEvents(getLogEventsRequest);
            logEventsForStream.addAll(getLogEventsResult.getEvents());
        } while (getLogEventsResult.getNextForwardToken() != null && !getLogEventsResult.getNextForwardToken().isEmpty());

        // now, save these events (lines) in a single StringBuilder variable
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(OutputLogEvent event : logEventsForStream) {
            dateTime = new DateTime(event.getTimestamp());
            stringBuilder
                    .append(dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss"))
                    .append(": ")
                    .append(event.getMessage())
                    .append("\n");
        }

        // finally, save StringBuilder as file
        try {
            // remove special characters from stream name (except for dash) and this will be the name of the S3 file
            fileName = logStream.getLogStreamName().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9-]", "");

            // create local temp file 
            File file = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".txt");

            // write StringBuilder to File
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, stringBuilder.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            // save file to S3
            s3Client.putObject(bucketName, fileName, file);

            // DELETE the file - this is important because there is a limit of 512mb of files that can be created and stored locally
            // so always better to create, save to S3 (or somewhere) and delete local files
            //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
            file.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            context.getLogger().log("failed to save file for stream name: " + logStream.getLogStreamName());
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS give us the possibility to use [export task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogsClient.html#createExportTask-com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.CreateExportTaskRequest-), you can use this run this task in your lambda in the following way, being from = yesterday and to = today:

```
public void exportTask(){
    CreateExportTaskRequest request = CreateExportTaskRequest.builder()
   .destination("yourS3bucket")
   .logGroupName(yourLogGroupName)
   .from(FROM)
   .to(TO).build(); 
   CloudWatchLogsClient cloudWatchLogsClient = CloudWatchLogsClient.builder()
   .region(YOUR_REGION).build();
   cloudWatchLogsClient.createExportTask(exportTaskRequest);
}
```